# Razor web pages: How do I create variable that is available to all pages?

Tags: c#, razor, webmatrix

I have a lot of pages that is using the same variables. I would like to create these in a single page so I dont have to type them over and over again. How do I do this?

I tried both _appStart.cshtml and _PageStart.cshtml, but when i run my content page i get error "the name selectedData does not exist in the current context"

Here is my _PageStart.cshtml: (tried _appstart.cshtml too)

```
@{
var db = Database.Open("razortest");
var selectQueryString  = "SELECT * FROM tbl_stasjon ORDER BY nr";
var selectedData = db.Query(selectQueryString);
}
```

And all of my pages includes this:

```
@foreach(var row in (selectedData)) {

html here...    

}
```

Comment: My first question would be why... but have you considered placing the code in a base `Controller` that your other controllers inherit from? Then you can use the `ViewBag`..

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I create a generic view model in MVC?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9423977/how-can-i-create-a-generic-view-model-in-mvc).  The way you are suggesting solving your problem in your question is very much against the [MVC design](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller).  The type of logic in your example should not exist in any View.

Comment: this is not MVC, but Web Pages. Im currently following this tutorial: http://www.w3schools.com/aspnet/webpages_intro.asp

Comment: When you say "using the same variables" are you using the same variable name or are you returning the same data in many pages?

Answer (score 2):

For a fairly straight-forward solution you could create a static class/method within `App_Code` that returns your query object and then call that method wherever you need it:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Web;
using WebMatrix.Data;

public static class MyClass
{
    public static IEnumerable<dynamic> GetData()
    {
        var db = Database.Open("razortest");
        var selectQueryString  = "SELECT * FROM tbl_stasjon ORDER BY nr";
        return db.Query(selectQueryString);
    }
}
```

Then in your scripts you can do:

```
@foreach(var row in MyClass.GetData()) {
    html here...
}
```

There will likely be more elegant and performant ways to achieve this but they depend on what exactly you're doing. For the purposes of following a tutorial this should serve your purposes.

Answer (score 0):

You could get use of the session and try to use a controller.

See

- [Adding a Controller](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-4/getting-started-with-aspnet-mvc4/adding-a-controller)
- [Adding a View](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-4/getting-started-with-aspnet-mvc4/adding-a-view)
- [Adding a Model](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-4/getting-started-with-aspnet-mvc4/adding-a-model)

Override `OnActionExecuting` within your controller (wihtin the constructor the Session is not available)

```
protected override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
{
    base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
    if (Session != null)
        Session["selectedData"] = "Hello World";
}
```

And within the Action

```
Public ActionResult View1(){
     return View(Session["selectedData"];
}
```

Within your view you can handle this data

```
@{
ViewBag.Title = Model;
}
```

That's a simple solution with a string. You can create strongly typed views and get a very comfotable way to handle this data within your views.

Comment: This isn't an MVC question.