# Razor WebPage: How to make data from the database alvailable to several pages?

Tags: razor, webmatrix, asp.net-webpages

My question is quite similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21246087/razor-web-pages-how-do-i-create-variable-that-is-available-to-all-pages).

I get the same data (attributes of objects, each row represents an object) from the database for two of my pages, one page to edit the data and one page to view it. To reduce redundant code and to improve maintaining I wanted to write the piece of code that loads the data only once.

My idea was to use a `_PageStart.cshtml`. But with that I only can store strings in the `PageData` array but not Objects.

So what is the best way to make the rows from the database available on several pages?

Here is how I get the data from the database:

```
var db = Database.Open("mydb");
String query = "select * from motors";
var rows = db.Query(query);

System.Data.DataTable motors = new System.Data.DataTable();
motors.Columns.Add("posX", typeof(int));
motors.Columns.Add("posY", typeof(int));

IEnumerator<dynamic> en = rows.GetEnumerator();
while (en.MoveNext()) {
    motors.Rows.Add(en.Current.posX, en.Current.posY);
}
```

I would like to access the DataTable `motors` on different pages.

Answer (score 1):

All you have to do is create a page that only has your code in it, Then on whatever page you want it displayed just use:

```
@RenderPage("~/yourpage.cshtml");
```

Comment: I tried to access the DataTable `motors`. Visual Studio (and the server once I run the page) says _The name 'motors' doesn't exist in the current context._

Comment: Sorry, you also need to put your output on the code page, Whatever you want displayed multiple times. The other option if you only want to access parts of data you can put the query in the top of your code in a layout page and then use @Page.motors top call it. But you need to name the variable motors as Page.motors instead.

Comment: What do you mean by "output"? And it's not possible to put the code in `yourpage.cshtml` and access the DataTable somehow like `@yourpage.motors`?

Comment: Can I see the full code of the page you have successfully displayed your DataTable? Then I can show you exactly what to do.